# Image over image using CSS position or z-index not work using mpdf

Tags: css, mpdf

I've built web app that create report page into PDF using mpdf with two images, signature and stamp, and I want to combine both of them on the same line, one in front and other in back.

I've tried using CSS both position and z-index unfortunately still not work using mpdf but work in HTML page.

This is the code

**CSS**

```
    <style>
        .back {
            z-index: 1;
            height: 80px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .front {
            z-index: 2;
            height: 150px;
            top: 0px;
            left: 50px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    </style>
```

**PHP**

```
<img class="back" src="<?= base_url() . 'assets/xyz/sign.png'; ?>" />
<img class="front" src="<?= base_url() . 'assets/xyz/stamp.png'; ?>" />
```

Does anyone have a solution to solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[mPDF supports absolute positioning](http://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/fixed-position-blocks.html), so you could wrap divs around both those images and then absolute position them.

```
<style>
    #back {
        z-index: 1;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #front {
        z-index: 2;
        width: 80px;
        height: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 50px;
    }
</style>

<div id="back"><img src="<?= base_url() . 'assets/xyz/sign.png'; ?>" /></div>
<div id="front"><img src="<?= base_url() . 'assets/xyz/stamp.png'; ?>" /></div>
```